# Numerical solutions with insufficient boundary conditions

Tags: computational-physics, classical-electrodynamics, boundary-conditions, differential-equations

Numerically is there a procedure to find at least one solution to differential equations given insufficient boundary conditions?

For example:

Consider electrodynamics in vacuum, and for initial conditions I have the value of the fields and their derivatives, at time t=0:

- on some closed spatial surface
- everywhere outside the surface
- at some *single point* inside the surface

If I am interested in solutions, these boundary conditions are insufficient to force a unique solution.  There are probably an infinite number of wave packet solutions.

Is there some numerical procedure to maybe guess a solution and then somehow "relax" it until it matches both the field equations and the boundary conditions?

And if so, is this possible in general or just with linear differential equations?

Comment: It sounds to me like you have sufficient boundary conditions, but don't know what starting value(s) to assume when running your numerical solution.  Is that correct?

Comment: If I could come up with valid initial conditions for the other locations at t=0, then yes I could start solving forward. That is one way to think of it.

Comment: Can you start with a feasible set of initial conditions, rather than a converged starting condition?  In other words, for an assumed problem where I know that all variables are non-negative, I would choose an "educated guess" (e.g., all positive values) for my starting variables, and let the numeric program that I am using converge the solution.

Comment: That would be assuming any errors "dampen out".  I'd expect (possibly incorrectly) that for linear equations, the errors wouldn't go away, and if I had non-linear equations the effects could even blow up.

Comment: And THAT is the difficulty in converging many numeric problems.  Often, you need very good starting guesses, or the problem diverges.  And very good starting guesses can only come from experience.